# Remove firestore snapshot listener not working (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code to start listening for changes in a specific directory of firestore:

```
func updateCart(){
   database.collection("Users").document(currentUserUUID!).collection("Transactions").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { event in
            let Active = event.document.data()["Active"] as? Bool
            let Type = event.document.data()["Instore"] as? Bool
            let Store = event.document.data()["Store"] as? String
            let TDate = event.document.data()["Date"] as? String

            if (Active == true) {
                print("New Transaction at \(Store!) - (Instore location:\(Type!)) on \(TDate!)")
                self.searchCart(Document: event.document.documentID)
                self.DocumentID = event.document.documentID
                self.startTransaction()
            }

            if (event.type == .modified && Active == false){
                print("Transaction at \(Store!) - (Instore location:\(Type!)) on \(TDate!) is no longer active or has been finalized")
                let updatedData = ["Total": "\(self.Total)","Saved": "\(self.Savings)"]
                database.collection("Users").document(currentUserUUID!).collection("Transactions").document(event.document.documentID).setData(updatedData, merge: true)
                self.completeTransaction()
                self.DocumentID = " "

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In viewDidLoad I run the function: updateCart(), but when the field Active in the database changes to false, I am trying to stop the listener in the app. I tried the following code but it does not stop the listener:

```
func detachListener() {
    let listener = database.collection("Users").document(currentUserUUID!).collection("Transactions").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        if error != nil{
            print(error as Any)
        }
    }
    listener.remove()
}
```

Comment: has anybody found the solution to this? i have used the weak refrence inside the block but it still happens. No matter what i try the listener is not removed.

Comment: Running into the same issue. `deinit` in the controller is being called, I am using a weak reference to self, and I am calling `remove()` in `deinit`. Not sure what else I am missing